# challenges in installing SharePoint 2013 SP1 on Windows Server 2016 OS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, service-pack

my customer has procured `windows server 2016` hence they want me to check whether `sharepoint 2013 SP1` is compatible with `Win 2016 OS` as PRODUCTION Server.
I didnt see much on this when i searched in net. Has anyone done this yet?
SP 2013 SP1 is installed on-premises in my client's staging environment.

Comment: What OS is being used in the staging environment?  Production should match otherwise it's not a good staging environment.

Comment: in staging, its WIN 2012 R2 OS only.Not Win 2016 .

Comment: As Waqas has stated, SP 2013 isn't supported on Windows Server 2016.  Also, why do you want your production environment to differ from your staging environment?

Comment: even though its called "staging", actually it doesnt replicate the Prod.env. in my prod. i have recommended  2WFE, 2 INDEX , 1 Sql Cluster [ with sql 2012 sp2 ] .but due to some cost factors and some other client concerns i could not replicate the same in staging. Client is yet to come up with h/w to me . But since they have strong partnership with Microsoft, so client is getting everyweek suggestions from MSFT to upgrade their s/w to latest MSFT s/w. :-) But i have rejected their demand now.

Comment: Staging doesn't have to match box for box but it most definitely should match OS and patch level, etc.

Comment: Thnx for the updates about the OS, patch level. BTW , I have one more doubt on Index Server partitioning. I will open  a new thread. It would be helpful,if you could provide some insights on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharepoint 2013 sp1 is not supported on windows server 2016 as well as sql server 2016.

There are few changes on windows 2016 which are not compatible with Sharepoint 2013.check this article.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#section4

Comment: Waqas, your answers in this forum related to infra. always helped me to take critical decisions for our customers. Hats Off !!

Comment: hi waqas now in july 2018 is still sp 2013 installation not supported  windows server 2016 datacener?